# Separation of Infinite-Dimensional Salient Convex Cones

Tags: convexity, hahn-banach-theorem

Let X be the set of all summable sequences of reals endowed with the $l^1$ norm.

That is, two elements of x are
$a=(a_1,a_2,....)$ and 
$b=(b_1,b_2,...)$ and $d(a,b) = \sum_n |a_n-b_n|$.

In this set I have two countable generated convex cones, A and B.

I can prove that $A \cap B = \{0\}$ and I would like to separate these cones. I’ve been attempting to use the closed,compact version of the Hahn-Banach sepesrtion theorem, but unfortunately, they do not have compact cross sections.

One property that I do have is that the cones are salient, and even more, they are cones of non-negative sequences. Is there a different separation theorem that I can use in this (slightly) infinite-dimensional setting?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, I don't know enough about your problem to guess how weak your hypotheses need to be. However, there is some literature on separating convex cones in locally convex spaces, which might be useful to you. The following might be good places to start

> *Dieudonné, Jean*, [**Sur la séparation des ensembles convexes**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02052480),  Math. Ann. **163** 1–3 (1966). [MR0194865](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=194865).
>
> *Klee, V.L.Jr.*, [**Separation properties of convex cones**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2032366), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. **6**, 313-318 (1955). [ZBL0064.35602](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0064.35602).